# returnKeyType is not changing while UITextField is active in iOS8

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

Is there any workaround of the situation when we need to change UIReturnKeyType in runtime?

```
[self.textField resignFirstResponder];

self.textField.returnKeyType = isNext ? UIReturnKeyNext : UIReturnKeyDone;

[self.textField reloadInputViews];

[self.textField becomeFirstResponder];
```

I tried almost all suggested variants, but anyway, in iOS 8 this doesn't work. In iOS 7 all works fine, "Done" button appears as expected